# Swift - Unwinding from Table View Controller in Container

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a `UIViewController` (HandlerViewController) with two containers in it (each associated with a table view controller to show records from database). When I click on one of the rows in any of the two containers, I see the detail view. In the detail view, I have a button (Cancel) that is linked to the unwind function in `HandlerViewController`. When that view loads, the tables in the containers are empty.

How can I repopulate them upon successfully unwinding? The `viewDidLoad()` in both table view controllers are already having code that populates the tables but it doesn't work when I unwind apparently.

Here is the layout:

[image]

If any more clarification is required I will be happy to provide it.

Comment: Try moving the code that loads the data in the viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear

Comment: @JonahStarling brilliant!!!!! Please post as answer so it help others that may be confused about this. oh and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view has already loaded when you unwind the segue and won't necessarily load again. You should move your code to ViewWillAppear.